# What is the use of DECIMAL(x,0)?

Tags: mysql

In a DECIMAL(M, D) column MySQL gives the option for the range of D to be 0 to 30.

Is there a subtle reason that I'm missing for the option of 0? Isn't a decimal with nothing after the decimal point an integer?

When and why would I want to specify a DECIMAL that has no decimal places?

Comment: Given the problem you had reading and comprehending the question in the first place, I disagree. Thank you for deleting your 'answer'.

Comment: Okay, those previous comments refer to http://stackoverflow.com/users/166390/pst who came in here didn't read my question, trampled all over it, edited the title, deleted his tracks and ran away.

Comment: This question has suffered a surprising number of edits, most of which have made it more difficult to read and a similar number restoring it. If you must add your own bit of butchery then, at the very least, don't correct my native English grammar with your incorrect second language version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The number range of the [DECIMAL type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fixed-point-types.html) is much greater than for an INTEGER or BIGINT. The greatest number you are able to store in a DECIMAL(65, 0) is 65 nines. The largest number in a BIGINT is 18446744073709551615.

DECIMAL(x, 0) is often a little more expensive for small numbers. Consider using a defined [INTEGER type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/integer-types.html) if your numbers are in the range for one of those.

---

The storage requirement in bytes for a DECIMAL(x, 0) field depends on the `x` according to this formula:

```
Storage = x / 9 + Leftover
Leftover = round_up((x % 9) / 2) (i.e., about half of the leftover digits)
```

You can read more about storage [requirements for numeric types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/storage-requirements.html#id693943) in the MySQL manual and compare for yourself.

Comment: So what you're saying is it's a way of fudging a VERYBIGINT?

Comment: Yes, I guess so. They had the datatype for storing numbers to a  specified numbers of digits and then just allowed the decimals part to be zero. It's probably trivial to have `D>=0` when you already have `D>=1`, and someone may need it someday. Note though that calculations on the field may very well be slower than on INTEGER fields; I haven't tried it but it's my gut feeling that you should find that out before doing heavy calculations using large DECIMAL values.

Answer (score 2):

Besides allowing to store values bigger than `BIGINT`, you can use `DECIMAL(x,0)` if you want to:

- allow values in the range `-9, ... , +9`: use `DECIMAL(1,0)` (uses 1 byte)
- allow values in the range `-99, ... , +99`: use `DECIMAL(2,0)` (uses 1 byte)
- allow values in the range `-999, ... , +999`: use `DECIMAL(3,0)` (uses 2 bytes)
- allow values in the range `-9999, ... , +9999`: use `DECIMAL(4,0)` (uses 2 bytes)

...

- allow values in the range `-999999999, ... , +999999999`: use `DECIMAL(9,0)` (uses 4 bytes)

... etc (up to `DECIMAL(65,0)` which uses 29 bytes)

Comment: This doesn't really explain the question, though. Why would you want this? Is it for the constraints on number of digits? Because for storage the TINYINT, SMALLINT, etc, are at least as good or better.

Answer (score 2):

In Mysql,
Decimal(3,2) means total 3 digits and 2 digits after decimal point like 3.42

Decimal(3,0) means in total 3 digits and no digit after decimal point like 345
Even if you write something beyond the given range in brackets of decimal Mysql will automatically update them to 000 or 999.

Answer (score 1):

In a biging you can only store a digit which is no larger than 18 446 744 073 709 551 615. This is 20 digits, but in a DECIMAL you can specify even a 65 digits to store. Also with int you can't constrait directly the number of digits to a low number (e.g. to one). So it is more flexible, and if you need to expand it on an existing database, it is easier.

Comment: What do you mean by "expand it on an existing database"? Also note that for smaller numbers there's already defined INTEGER types (TINYINT, SMALLINT, ...) which use the same amount of storage (or less in some cases, e.g., if your  number is always < 255 you'll need 1 byte with TINYINT or 2 bytes with DECIMAL(3, 0). I understand the possible value of just the constraints imposed by DECIMAL, though.